# Is it possible to change the default font color of the WPF Richtextbox control

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I need to change the default text color (without setting the font color)

I have styled the textbox so the background is dark and I need the text to be light.  (Setting the foreground brush does not work the text is still black)

Comment: Foreground works perfectly as it should. What else r u doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the XAML below and it works fine:

```
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox Foreground="Green" Background="Gray"/>
</Grid>
```

You may be applying the foreground in a Style that is being overriden?

Comment: Thanks it turned out that a designer was overwriting foreground in a template that i didn't realize was being applied